# Probability that all red cards are assigned a number less than or equal to 15

Tags: probability, combinatorics, self-learning

I have 10 red and 10 blue cards. I shuffle the cards and then label the cards based on their orders: I write the number one on the first card, the number two on the second card, and so on. What is the probability that

a) All red cards are assigned numbers less than or equal to 15?
b) Exactly 8 red cards are assigned numbers less than or equal to 15?

I know that the total number of ways to arrange 20 cards is $20!$. How do I proceed further?

Comment: Hw many ways are there to arrange them so the last $5$ cards are blue?

Comment: For the last 5 cards to be blue, we need to arrange 10 red and remaining 5 blue cards in the first 15 positions. The number of ways for this is 15!/(10!*5!). Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite... That assumes the red cards and blue cards are all indistinguishable except by color.  But $20!$ assumes that all cards are indistinguishable.  You need to be more consistent.  Have both numerator and denominator be where cards are distinguishable, or have both numerator and denominator be where cards are indistinguishable.

Comment: Ok, since the cards are distinguishable, the number of ways to have 5 blue cards at the last is 15!. Is that correct? Many thanks.

Comment: Not quite... if the cards are $R_1,R_2,R_3,\dots,R_{10},B_1,B_2,\dots,B_{10}$ the count of $15!$ is the number of ways such that the last five cards are *very specifically* $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4,B_5$ in that order, but the last five cards being blue might have been blue cards different than those specific five or in a different order than that.

Comment: @JMoravitz Can't we adjust for the last five blue balls being in any order by multiplying by 5!? That gives us a total of 15!*5!?

Comment: @ForumWhiner No, that still makes the mistake that it is very specifically the balls $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4,B_5$ who are at the end in some order, maybe $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4,B_5$ or maybe $B_4,B_2,B_5,B_1,B_3$ or some other order of very specifically those five balls... It doesn't allow for the blue balls at the end being $B_7,B_2,B_{10},B_8,B_1$ or any other arrangement with a blue ball at the end who is not one of the first five.

Comment: @ForumWhiner if you want to use a denominator of $20!$, then your numerator should have been $\binom{10}{5}\times 5!\times 15!$, the $\binom{10}{5}$ that you left out coming from having chosen *which* of the blue balls appear at the end, then $5!$ for in what order those selected blue balls appeared at the end, then $15!$ for how to arrange the rest.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Okay, got it. Just one last question - why $10C_5$ and why not $10P_5$ where P stands for permutation since the order matters here?

Comment: $\binom{10}{5}\cdot 5! = 10\frac{5}{~}$, or using your notation..... $~_{10}C_5\cdot 5! = ~_{10}P_5$.  Order mattering was accounted for in the $5!$ term already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the number of red cards be $N_1$ and that of blue ones $N_2$ (in your case $N_1=N_2=10$) and ask in how many permutations $k$ red cards will be among the $K$ first.

The answer is
$$
\binom {N_1}k\binom {N_2}{K-k}K!(N_1+N_2-K)!
$$
where $\binom {N_1}k\binom {N_2}{K-k}$ stays for the number of ways to choose $k$ red cards and $K-k$ blue ones, $K!$ - for the number of ways to permute them, and $(N_1+N_2-K)!$ - for the number of ways to permute the rest cards. It remains to divide the result by $(N_1+N_2)!$ to obtain:
$$
p=\frac{\binom{N_1}{k}\binom{N_2}{K-k}}{\binom{N_1+N_2}K}.
$$
This result can be of course obtained also directly by counting the respective combinations.

Comment: Thanks! @user. Does this answer a) or b)? What corresponds to k and K in part a)?

Comment: @ForumWhiner a) $K=15, k=10$; b) $K=15, k=8$.

Comment: Ok, I think I finally get it thanks to your formula. Part a) We divide the balls into 15+5. There are 15!*5! combinations to divide this. Then among the first 15, 10balls have to be red and 5 balls have to be blue. For this, there are 10C10*10C5 combinations. Putting these together we get 10C10*10C5*15!*5!. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @ForumWhiner The correct result according to my formula is $\frac{10!15!}{5!}$. It seems that you got it correctly.

Comment: Yes $10C10 * 10C5 * 15! * 5!$  indeed comes out to be $\frac{10!15!}{5!}$. I was wondering if my reasoning makes sense.

Comment: @ForumWhiner As far as I can see it is the same reasoning as given in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106609/discussion-between-forumwhiner-and-user).

Comment: I don't understand why there are $15!*5!$ combinations of the balls and cards. Shouldn't it be considered the repetition of colors? Like in the permutation of letters, where the nuumber ways I can make different words with 10 R's and 10 B's is $\frac{20!}{10!*10!}$

Comment: @Guilherme In my derivation I assumed that all cards are distinguishable. But of course the same result can be obtained if we assume the cards of the same color to be indistinguishable (as pointed out in the end of my answer).