# Calculating the probability of picking a certain hand of cards from a deck

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Suppose you had a deck of $12$ cards consisting of $3$ blue cards and $9$ red cards. If you can only pick $3$ cards, what is the probability that you will have picked $3$ red cards? Also, how would you solve the general case?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: Well, I'm unsure how to calculate for multiple cards picked. I know that if you pick 1 card then the probability that it is red is 9/12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3613151) the probability in a general case is:
$$
\frac{\binom{N_R}{k_R}\binom{N_B}{K-k_R}}{\binom{N_R+N_B}K},
$$
where $N_R$ and $N_B$ are the overall numbers of red and blue cards, respectively, $K$ is the number of drawn cards, $k_R$ is the number of drawn red cards.

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways of choosing three cards out of 12 cards is given by $\binom{12}{3}.$

There are $\binom{9}{3}$ ways to choose three red cards out 9 red cards.

Therefore the answer is $\dfrac{\binom{9}{3}}{\binom{12}{3}}.$

---

Alternatively you can imagine picking them one by one.

Let $E_i$ be the event of getting a red card in the i-th draw for $i=1,2,3$. Then

$$P(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3)=P(E_1)P(E_2|E_1)P(E_3|E_1\cap E_2) = \frac{9}{12}\frac{8}{11}\frac{7}{10}$$